# When does dragging select elements on an HTML page?

Tags: html, browser

If you go to a page like youtube.com and drag the mouse around while holding down the left button all kinds of things get selected.  In the image below, for example, I'm just dragging the mouse along the red arrow and all  the stuff at the top got selected and turned blue.
[image]

But if I create a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nxwLc/ - with a simple div and drag the mouse around with the left button down, I'm not able to select anything. I can even drag completely around the box without selecting it.

Does anyone know what the difference is?

Thanks

```
<div id="box1"></div>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code here: the "link to external sites must include code" restriction is there for a reason.

Comment: What code would you like me to post?

Comment: The code from your Fiddle would be preferable: don't link to live code.

Comment: Also, see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You misread my question.  I didn't post a link to live code, I posted an image.

Comment: The Fiddle you linked to contains code that produces something, and I understand why you didn't include the code since it was for demonstration purposes only, but it just looks silly to have `enter code here` at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I did post the jsfiddle code but somehow the Stackoverflow "enter code here" got displayed instead of the code.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **selection** (highlight) you see is being applied to **textual content** elements specifically text and images. In your example you have nothing but a `<div>` element

Now you'll have something to highlight: http://jsfiddle.net/nxwLc/2/

```
<div id="box1"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100/cf5"/> asdasdasd</div>
```

Also worth noting that Firefox will highlight exactly *what should be highlighted*, while in Chrome the highlight area will have unspecific and also unpredicted results, element-related, keeping an eye to line-heights content-flows etc... strange in any case.

```
                 Chrome                  vs.              Firefox
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that.  I noticed that Chrome highlighted blocks that I didn't even seem to be touching, and wondered why.